# Incomplete Implementation View Controller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, implementation, incomplete-type

I am making an app in Xcode. It is my first app and I'm getting an error that says "Incomplete Implementation" in my ViewController.m file. Here is the line of code where I get the error:

```
@implementation ViewController : UIViewController;
```

Answer (score 3):

remove semicolon at the end of that line:

```
@implementation ViewController : UIViewController
```

Also check if in your implementation block you implement all methods declared in class interface and in protocols your class conforms to

Comment: It didn't work. It is still showing incomplete implementation

Comment: post more relevant code? That error may indicate that you declared some methods in your class but have not implemented them

Comment: This is all of the code I have up until the error. The last line is where I get the error.

//  ViewController.m
//  FordyceSchools
//
//  Created by Brandon Payne on 9/24/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Brandon Payne. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: It could also mean that your class is implementing an interface, and you haven't added all the methods required by the interface to your .m file as well.